# CSS transition on background-image/size very bumpy, how can I make it smoother?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm making a sort of intro movie for a game and thought it would be nice to do it with CSS.
Some parts of the animation are really bumpy but I'm not sure why. Depending on using different `transition-timing-function` different parts of the animation go smooth or bumpy.
I don't understand why some parts move very smooth and then suddenly start to stutter (during the same transition).

Am I doing something wrong? Are there better ways of doing this?

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YEvCU/)

HTML

```
  var screen1 = $('#screen1');
  var screen2 = $('#screen2');
```

JavaScript

```
  screen1.css({
      'background': 'url(http://uniquenaturewallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/3d-underwater-Wallpaper.jpg)',
          'background-position': 'left center',
          'background-size': '100%',
          '-webkit-filter': 'none'
  });
  screen2.css({
      'opacity': '0'
  });

  setTimeout(function () {
      screen2.css({
          'opacity': '1'
      });
  }, 20000);


<div id="screen1"></div>
<div id="screen2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#screen1, #screen2 {
    background: black;
    background-size: 150%;
    background-position: 100% 50%;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 30s ease-in, -webkit-filter 20s ease-in 8s;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really old, but I also struggled with this until I found a good way to implement `scale`

check out the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/YEvCU/6/

I use `transform: scale(3)` then animate it to `transform: scale(1)`

HTML

```
<div id="screen1"></div>
<div id="screen2"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
  var screen1 = $('#screen1');
  var screen2 = $('#screen2');

  screen1.css({
      'background': 'url(http://uniquenaturewallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/3d-underwater-Wallpaper.jpg)',
          'background-position': 'left center',
          'background-size': '100%',
          '-webkit-transform': 'scale(1)',
          'transform': 'scale(1)',
          '-webkit-filter': 'none'
  });
  screen2.css({
      'opacity': '0'
  });

  setTimeout(function () {
      screen2.css({
          'opacity': '1'
      });
  }, 20000);
```

CSS:

```
#screen1, #screen2 {
    background: black;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: 100% 50%;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 30s ease-in, -webkit-filter 20s ease-in 8s;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I understand that but, the only change needed was to add `scale` simple as that. Plus this is an old question 9 months. I just thought id share...

Comment: Thanks, that is much smoother.